# How to check if an value matches all conditions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a function that checks if a value matches all conditions that are Listed somewhere. I've been thinking how to do it with delegates, but nothing came into my mind. Because I dont know how to check if every function in delegate returns true. Here's code I tried. it gives me *method name expected* error.

```
public List<bool> conditionsToCheck;
    public bool isWordValid(string wordToCheck)
    {
        bool[] checkResults = new bool[conditionsToCheck.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < conditionsToCheck.Count; i++)
        {
            checkResults[i] = conditionsToCheck[i](wordToCheck);
        }
        //then I check if all bool values in checkResults contain true
    }
    public void AddConditionToCheck(bool condition)
        {
            conditionsToCheck.Add(condition);
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do.  `conditionsToCheck` is a collection of `bool` values.  How do you expect to *execute* a `bool` value?  In what way do you expect a `string` to "match" a `bool` value?

Comment: It is something like that: `public bool hasMoreThanFourChars(string str) { return (str.Length>4); }`

Comment: And where is that `hasMoreThanFourChars` method in the code?  How does it relate to the code shown?  Perhaps you could provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
public List<Func<string,bool>> conditionsToCheck = new();

public bool isWordValid(string wordToCheck) =>
    !conditionsToCheck.Any(c => !c(wordToCheck));

public void AddConditionToCheck(Func<string,bool> condition) =>
    conditionsToCheck.Add(condition);
```

The example code is not tested, but intended to show how it works.

Each condition is a function that must be evaluated later. Here's how to use it:

```
obj.AddConditionToCheck(w => w.Length > 4);
```

The `isWordValid()` function then calls all those conditions and stops at the first that returns false (no need to continue).

Docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2):

Okay lets list some conditions just for the sake of example:

```cs
public bool IsCool(string str)
{
  return str == "Cool";
}

public bool IsLong(string str)
{
  return str.Length > 100;
}

public bool IsQuestion(string str)
{
  return str.Contains("?");
}
```

We can group these in a collection of delegates like so:

```cs
# Required to use Func Delegate
using System;

// Func<string, bool> means a function that accepts a string parameter and returns a bool
var rules = new List<Func<string, bool>>();

// Notice we aren't doing IsCool(), we don't want to invoke the method 
// but rather pass the method itself as a parameter to Add()
rules.Add(IsCool);
rules.Add(IsLong);
rules.Add(IsQuestion);
```

And then check if all of the functions return true:

```cs
var str = "Bleh";
var pass = true;
foreach(var rule in rules)
  pass = pass && rule.Invoke(str);
```

---

**Unneeded but cool improvements**

We can use the [Linq library](http://dotnetpattern.com/linq-all-operator) to make it read nicer:

```
using System.Linq;

var pass = rules.All(rule => rule.Invoke(str));
```

And if we are feeling wild, add an extension method:

```
public static class String Extensions
{
  public static bool Satisfies(this String str, params Func<string, bool>[] rules)
  {
    return rules.All(rule => rule.Invoke(str);
  }
}

"Woah!".Satisfies(IsLong, IsCool, IsQuestion);
```

Comment: I don't have enough words to thank you! You are my savior. But this `var rules = new List<Func<string, bool>>();` line gives me an error: _The type or namespace name 'Func<,>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?._ I checked a lot of articles, but found nothing.

Comment: Nevermind, It's ```using System;```. Thank you!

Comment: @Omis updated to include this, sorry about that!